# How can I click on a div and have it open a targeted div, then have the targeted div close when i click on a 3rd div?

Tags: javascript, dom, toggle, addeventlistener

I have a gallery of 20 images and each image corresponds to a div with text in it.
When i click on an image, the text should appear. When i click on the next image, that images text should appear WHILE closing the previous text div from the 1st image i clicked on.

So only one text box should be visible at one time.

so far i have this:

```
attachToggleListener("leifr","rosenvold");
attachToggleListener("damians","smith");
attachToggleListener("megan","adam");

 function attachToggleListener (buttonID, divID) {
  var myTrigger = document.getElementById(buttonID);
  if (myTrigger != null) {
    myTrigger.addEventListener("click", toggleDiv);
    myTrigger.targetDiv = divID; 
    }
   }

 function toggleDiv(evt) {
   var target = document.getElementById(evt.currentTarget.targetDiv);
    if (target.style.display === "block")
        { target.style.display = "none"; }
    else
        { target.style.display = "block"; }
   }
```

the text appears when i click on the image, but it does not close when i click on the next image.
as it sits now, I can click on 4 images and 4 text divs will appear and only be removed when i click the image that made it appear.

Again what i was expecting was to click on an image "leifr" > the text box appears "rosenvold" >click on a second image "damians" > the second text box appears "smith" while the 1st text box "rosenvold" disappears

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your toggleDiv function to read all possible divs. I would suggest you to do 2 things.

1. Add a class to your divs. Say for example `image_helper_text`.
2. Modify your toggleDiv function to look something like

   ```
   function toggleDiv(evt) {
       var target = document.getElementById(evt.currentTarget.targetDiv);
       var targets = document.getElementsByClassName("image_helper_text");

       // This will remove all other divs.
       if (targets && Array.isArray(targets) && targets.length) {
         targets.forEach((each) => {
         if (
           each.id !== evt.currentTarget.targetDiv &&
           each.style.display === "block"
         ) {
            each.style.display = "none";
           }
         });
       }
       if (target.style.display === "block") {
         target.style.display = "none";
       } else {
         target.style.display = "block";
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply! I tried this code and added the class to my text blocks divs and for some reason it is producing the same result as before.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example on how you can toggle between image captions. You have to keep track of the currently visible image caption (`previousCaption`) and then when a new image is clicked, simply hide `previousCaption` and display the new one.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".image");
let previousCaption = null; //currently visible image caption
images.forEach((img) => {
  const caption = img.querySelector(".caption");
  img.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (previousCaption) previousCaption.classList.toggle("hide");
    caption.classList.toggle("hide");
    previousCaption = caption;
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1em;
}

.image {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid;
}

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="caption hide">caption1</div>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <div class="caption hide">caption2</div>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <div class="caption hide">caption3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I duplicated my page and plugged this code in and changed all the classes to match and none of the text divs opened upon a image click, is there something im missing here or overlooking?

Comment: Did you properly link your javascript code and html code through the `script` tag? Also check on the console for any errors. You might want to include your entire code (html/css)  in your post so that I can debug it.

Answer (score 0):

**RESPONSE**

Here is another way to do it.

**HTML**

```html
<button data-target-id="470bec9d-a334-46cb-a7ff-01f4369120a7">Show Image #1</button>
<div id="470bec9d-a334-46cb-a7ff-01f4369120a7" class="">
  <label>Image #1</label>
  <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/8711/8711519.png">
</div>
<br>
<br>
<!-- ... etc ... -->
```

**CSS**

```css
img {
  max-width: 100px;
}

div {
  display: none;
}

div.show {
  display: block;
}
```

**JS**

```js
// Data
const dataList = [
    { image: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/8711/8711519.png', text: 'Image #1' },
  { image: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/8711/8711531.png', text: 'Image #2' },
  { image: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/8711/8711524.png', text: 'Image #3' },
  { image: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/8711/8711522.png', text: 'Image #4' },
  { image: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/8711/8711521.png', text: 'Image #5' },
];

// Loop through data and render on screen
for (const data of dataList) {
  const { image, text } = data;
  // Generate Random ID
  const id = crypto.randomUUID();

  // Create Button
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.setAttribute('data-target-id', id);
  btn.innerText = `Show ${text}`;
  document.body.appendChild(btn);

  // Create Div with data
  const el = document.createElement('div');
  el.setAttribute('id', id);
  el.innerHTML = `<label>${text}</label><img src="${image}">`;
  document.body.appendChild(el);

  // Create Spacers ( new lines )
  const br = document.createElement('br');
  document.body.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  document.body.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
}

// Attach Event Listener to buttons
function attachButtonListeners() {
  const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  for (const button of buttons) {
    button.addEventListener('click', toggleShowHide);
  }
}

// show / hide div with data
function toggleShowHide({ target }={}) {
  const { targetId } = target.dataset;
  const div = document.getElementById(targetId);
  if (div.classList.contains('show')) {
    div.classList.remove('show')
  } else {
    div.classList.add('show')
  }
}

// Run event listener
attachButtonListeners();
```